# Return 3 elements from function C++

Tags: c++, return, divide-and-conquer

I want to solve a problem, which needs the largest sum of the subarray and it's position. The program's solution is in pseudocode from the book Introductions to algorithms, however it contains a returning which contains 3 elements (low,high,sum). What can I do about this? How can I return three elements? The program is easily understandable, however the returning makes me unable to transform it to c++.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can either create a struct/class, use a vector/array or pass variables by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a struct containing 3 `int`s and return that from the function:

```
struct data
{
 int low, mid, high;
};

data fun( /* args ... */ )
{
  // ...
  return {low, mid, high};  
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to name the structure explicitly, you could just return a `std::tuple` containing 3 `int`s.

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> fun( /* args ... */ )
{
  // ...
  return {low, mid, high};  
}
```

In either case, at the call site you can write:

```
auto [low, mid, high] = fun();
```